# is there a code playground that supports twig?

Tags: twig

I write a lot of twig, but I can't find a code playground that supports it. I've looked at a dozen or so playgrounds while googling around, to no avail. Does anyone know of one? Or is it possible to pull twig.js into codepen, which supports external js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://twigfiddle.com/ looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: You'd think with a name like that it would have turned up in my searches!

Comment: Actually, if you'd like to find a playground for almost any language just google its name + fiddle

Comment: Heh. I spent a couple hours searching. There a many that don't use the word fiddle